# Amount of labelled simple directed graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I know that there are already several questions to this topic, but I haven't found a satisfying answer so far. Given the number of labelled vertices $V=\{1,...,n\}$, how many simple directed graphs are there? I found out that the answer is $2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$, but how come? By manually checking how many graphs there are for different $n$ I know that the formula seems to work but why so?
If this is a duplicate, please direct me to an answer, I couldn't find any myself.

Comment: There are $\binom{n}2$ pairs of vertices; for each of these you have two choices: join them by an edge or not.